# How to be placed off hold

Tags: discussion, help-center

I have a question about my Biology Stack Exchange post: [Reference Request: Nucleotides as adjoints](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/51168/reference-request-nucleotides-as-adjoints)

I followed up on the requests for an edit immediately after it was given by adding a significant amount of new content to my post.

After the first day of no response, I bumped my post by adding a comment.

4 days later and I'm still on hold despite having had no reply to know if my changes are adequate or how to update them if it's not.

Please advise

Ricardo Rademacher

Comment: People can vote to reopen your post. It takes 5 votes. Your question is in the reopen review queue. You can also use the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/the-biosphere) to attract attention to your post. I did post a link to your question in the chat but I cannot vote to reopen as mod votes are binding. So I don't vote unless I am 100% sure.

Comment: Odd system that lets 5 people/votes now serve as a gatekeeper for the thousands of other people/votes simply because my initial wording wasn't enough.  Wouldn't it be easier to delete this (on hold) and simply re-post the new content given that no one is asking me to modify anything and I'm just waiting on 5 people to notice?